# I can not seem to get the android_id

Tags: java, android

Here is the code i am using

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Do I need to add permission to my manifest to have access to this variable?

Comment: Are you working in the simulator or a real device?

Comment: real device, it just crashes the application when i try to access the variable, if i comment out that line the application runs properly

Comment: i moved it from being declared in the class to calling it in a function, works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i set android_id in onCreate now it works

```
private String android_id;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```